# Error: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send information from 'App.js' to 'Display.js' (which is a functional component) through props. But I am getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

The same code works when changing the 'Display.js' from a functional component to a class component.

App.js

```js
<div className="component-app">
  <Display value={this.state.next || this.state.total || "0"}></Display>
</div>
```

Display.js (functional component)

```
cconst display = (props)=>(
    <div>
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>
    </div>
);
```

Display.js (class component)

```
class Display extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div >
          <div>{this.props.value}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

The code for Display.js (class component) works, but why does functional component not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is for class based components only. Try like this

```
const display = (props)=>(
    <div>
        <div>{props.value}</div>
    </div>
);
```